# Easy way to get daily pageviews (different to each url)?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I need to display daily pageviews in my wordpress site. The problem is I need it to be url aware I mean not count visits for the whole site but just count how many visits the current URL had. Is there an easy way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this plugin:

http://ajaydsouza.com/wordpress/plugins/top-10/

It will count the number of page views on your single posts on a daily as well as overall basis.

Answer (score 0):

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/pixelstats/

Counts not only the pageviews but also the RSS viewed articles.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [Wordpress.com stats plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/stats/) or [Google Analytics](http://google.com/analytics).

There is also a [Google Analytics Wordpress plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-analytics-for-wordpress/)

Comment: But your links don't help the **display** this information, just to have it, I haven't yet found a way to use this plugin like this.

Comment: @Akinator If you have the data, what is keeping you from viewing it?

Comment: @jordanstephens (I may be mistaken!!) but: This is a quite complex plugin that for you to access and call that information you would have to be **quite** proficient in PHP, no to mention if you have to modify it. I just don't see an easy way to use this plugin and display informetion so (by no means I want to be agressive) I don't see how this question could actually help to **display** the pageviews of a post :)

Comment: Couldn't use either of the plugins. There is one that is supposed to do the trick but I cannot display the info. It says:

Comment: 'getUserPerDay( $days, $frontend )'

* shows average number of visitors per day of the last _$days_ days
* default on dashboard (see it with mouse over number) = "Latest Counts - Days" in options
* $frontend: 0 echo, 1 return output

Comment: How do I display that function? I put php tags, writed '$days=1; $frontend=0;' and then copied the function, but I get an error saying the function is undefined. I don't know much about php. Does anybody know how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

you can use wp post views http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-postviews/

i've used it before. you won't get analytics but if you include the `post views function` in your page you can see how much.

it also has options, like whether to count bots or not.

Comment: Thanks I thought it was just what I needed. But it only counts post views and I need to count views of search pages.

Comment: I need to get pageviews from any page on the site, not pages in the sense of single posts. I should have pointed that out.

Answer (score 0):

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/top-10/

WordPress doesn't count page views by default. Top 10 will count the number of page views on your single posts on a daily as well as overall basis. You can then display the page view count on individual posts and pages as well as display a list of most popular posts based on page views.